# How Google Play do to implement auto Updates?

Tags: android, google-play

I have seen that **Google Play** implements a great tool to auto update Apps, how do they do that?

if it's a broadcast receiver, how to make it listen a web service ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use Google Cloud Messaging, it is a push notification service.

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: Yes, this is what i'm looking for, thanks edthethird

Comment: glad I could help.  I'm an engineer at [Kinvey](http://www.kinvey.com/), and we are building an Android Library to make this even easier to use.

Comment: Great, i love what you doing, i support guys like you. Good luck

Answer (score 3):

**How It Works**
The Google Play services client library

Automatic Updates

Devices running Android 2.2 and newer and that have the Google Play Store app automatically receive updates to Google Play services. Enhance your app with the most recent version of Google Play services without worrying about your users' Android version.

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html

The Basic Idea behind is check version of software as it contains a Unique key and a version Number if Google find the difference of Version with same key between client and server version it allow application update

Comment: thank you for your explanation, but what i need to know is how to implement programmatically a small app that can listen a webservice like Google play do with updates.

Comment: You need a client who will check your Webservice after a certain period of time to find key and version number.So each time client have internet connectivity webserver can listen the client to provide information.If you find client need update just allow to download new product

Comment: by using a broadcast receiver ?

Comment: Yes the idea is same Broadcast reciever to listen webservice,

Comment: i think i will need also a AlarmManager.

Comment: There might be some paid Applications to achieve this service but you need to upload your application to server of the vendor as the need it to match your Application Key and Version number.